# Containment of $c_0$ in projective tensor products

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and denote by $X\hat{\otimes}_\pi Y$ the projective tensor product.

**Question:**
If $X\hat{\otimes}_\pi Y$ contains an isomorphic copy of $c_0$, must then $X$ or $Y$ contain an isomorphic copy of $c_0$ also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no. Bourgain and Pisier have given a counterexample (A construction of $\mathcal{L}_\infty$-spaces and related Banach spaces. Bol. Soc. Bras. Mat. 14, No. 2, 109-123 (1983). See Zbl 0586.46011 https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0586.46011 ).

Comment: Dear Prof. Werner, thank you very much for such a quick reply and pointing me to such an interesting paper!